# I'm new to coding and I was having an error with my tic tac toe game

Tags: python-3.x, 2d-games

I was makeing a tic tac toe game using a video as help so i will admit it is not really me making it but im extremely new to coding and this is the way i wanted to learn.I was using Repl.it.  When I was done with the code I eventually ran it to test it, played a game by myself and then went to show my friend, after showing some of the code, we tried to play it and then i got an error but I swear I didn't change anything. The error basically said "Typeerror: unsupported opperand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'"

It said error with lines 170, 34 , and 60 which i will put in the code section
Here is the link to the entire project --->https://repl.it/@JoshMayes/Tic-Tac-Toe

I haven't tried much and I appologise for that due to my excessive inexperience with coding I figured it might be better if I just went straight to the experts

```py
   def play_game():

     #Display the initial board
     display_board()

     while game_still_in_progress:

       #Go through the turn procedure for the current player
       handle_turn(current_player) <----- line 34

       #check if the game has ended
       check_if_game_over()

       #Flip to the other player
       flip_player()
     # The game has ended
     if winner == "X" or winner == "O":
       print(winner + " player won!")
     elif winner == None:
       print("Cat's game!")




    while not valid:

       while position not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        position + input("Invalid input. Choose a position from 1-9: ")

       position = int(position - 1)  <-------Line 60

       if board [position] == "-":
         valid = True
       else:
         print("Invalid Placement. Position Taken. Choose another Position")


      play_game() <---- line 170
```

BTW link to the whole thing here --->https://repl.it/@JoshMayes/Tic-Tac-Toe

I expected the game to just work due to it working 5 mins before it had an error, and I could have sworn I didn't change anything but reload the page because there was a message telling me to do so. But when attempting to play it for the second time it didn't work.

Comment: I could see that this is your first post, so welcome to stackoverflow :))<br/>
I'm not python developer, I use java instead. As pranja said, and as the error suggests, you save position as string, so you should convert it first to int before you subtract 1 from it.<br/>
Consider to mark pranja's answer as accepted if your issue is now resolved.<br/>
Also you needn't to swear that you didn't change the code, the code contained the bug from the very beginning, it is just that the scenario that fired the bug didn't occur at your first time trying it.<br/>
Finally, take it easy when the code break

Answer (score 2):

Update this 2 line

```py
position = input("Invalid input. Choose a position from 1-9: ")
position = int(position) - 1  <-------Line 60
```

Comment: THX that fixed it! You guys are great straight to the point cant thank you enough.